# How does Windows wireless display work?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I usually extend my PC screen to Samsung Galaxy Tab 6 Lite table as follows:

1. I used to connect both my PC and Tablet to same WiFi (thinking this feature works on WiFi).
2. Turning on second screen on Samsung tab.
3. Hit Windows + K on PC and then select tablet from the menu.

This is explained [here](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00088544/):
Today we had power outage and my WiFi router switched off. Surprisingly PC display extended to table was still working! I checked my PC bluetooth and it was off!! So I was guessing how it works?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How does Windows wireless display work?

It use Miracast which is direct wireless connection between the 2 devices and does not require a working internet connection:

> Miracast is based on the peer-to-peer Wi-Fi Direct standard. It allows sending up to 1080p HD video (H.264 codec) and 5.1 surround sound (AAC and AC3 are optional codecs, mandated codec is linear pulse-code modulation – 16 bits 48 kHz 2 channels). The connection is created via WPS and therefore is secured with WPA2. IPv4 is used on the Internet layer. On the transport layer, TCP or UDP are used. On the application layer, the stream is initiated and controlled via RTSP, RTP for the data transfer.

Source: [Miracast - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast)